# 'this' vs. 'bind.(this)' vs. passing an event to an event handler, React JS vs. vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events

I'm on my *long winding* journey to understand the ***this*** keyword in JavaScript (I was relieved to learn that Remy Sharp, creator of JS Bin also struggled with the *this* keyword in his early days -- so don't lose hope you newbs out there).

1. I was doing [this React JS tutorial](https://youtu.be/ZnRFerIP8aA?t=1172) and at 19:32 there was some interesting code that uses *this*, and the *event* as an argument to a function:

   ```
    // code snippet 1 

      changeColor(event) {
        this.setState({
          color: event.target.value
        });  
      }

    // code snippet 2

      <input value={this.state.color} onChange={this.changeColor.bind(this)}/>
   ```

So I thought I'd play around with *this* and *event* in vanilla JavaScript.

2. This worked:

   ```
    //javascript 

    function myFunction1() {

      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = this.event.target.value;
                             //this works too: event.target.value;

    }

    //HTML

    <button onclick="myFunction1()" value="blah1" >Click me1</button>

    <p id="demo1"></p>
   ```
3. This worked:

   ```
    //javascript 

    function myFunction2(objButton) {

      document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = objButton.value;

    }

    //HTML

    <button onclick="myFunction2(this)" value="blah2" >Click me2</button>

    <p id="demo2"></p>
   ```
4. Why did this not work?

   ```
    //javascript

    function myFunction3() {

      document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = this.value;

    }

    //HTML

    <button onclick="myFunction3.bind(this)" value="blah3" >Click me3</button>

    <p id="demo3"></p>
   ```
5. Why did this not work?

   ```
    //javascript 

    function myFunction4(event) {

      document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = event.target.value;

    }

    //HTML

    <button onclick="myFunction4.bind(this)" value="blah4" >Click me4</button>

    <p id="demo4"></p>
   ```

To summarize, why did (4) and (5) not work?

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/cezidi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> onclick="myFunction3.bind(this)"
> ```

The return value of `bind` is a *new function*. **When** you call that function, `myFunction3` is called with the `this` value specified as the first argument to `bind`.

You never call that function.

The same reason applies to example 5.

If you want to call the function, use `call` or `apply`. `bind` is for setting up a new function to call later (usually repeatedly).

Comment: Holy sh*t, (4) worked after I changed `onclick="myFunction3.bind(this)"` to `onclick="myFunction3.bind(this)()"`. **However (5) continues to not work probably because I'm improperly using `event` in the function argument. What am I doing wrong with (5)? Thanks!**

Comment: You aren't calling the function with any arguments. So `event` is `undefined`.

Comment: Then why does it work in (1) ... i.e., calling the function `changeColor` without an argument even though the function expects the `event` argument. Thanks!

Comment: @user1883050 — Because you aren't creating an `onclick` / `onchange` attribute. The `changeColor` function *is* the event listener.

Comment: Thank you for patiently answering. One last question (for now). If one were to add an argument to this function: `onclick="myFunction3.bind(this)"`, what would it look like? Something like this? `onclick="myFunction3.bind(arg1, this)"` Or would one have to use currying (or something else)? (Anyone should feel free to respond here.)

Comment: Have you read [the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)?

Comment: Not really. I find it hard to understand it. But I'll read it now, thanks for all the awesome help!